# Personalized app version

Tags: ios, iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a problem with my application on Appstore. There are a few clients on whose device the app failed to install or hangs ( something happened during the database update/migration, but not crash ).

Is there any possibility I could make an executable which can be sent to him and only he can install it, similarly to an ad-hoc-like distribution method ? This would be a special "debug" version, which enables file sharing in itunes and some logging features, not something I'd share with anybody else or make public.

Can this be accomplished somehow ?

Thanks.

Comment: Ad-hoc distribution is the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's what services like TestFlight are used for.

I recommend you that one, it's the most popular and reliable

http://testflightapp.com/

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, this TestFlight is really awesome.

Answer (score 0):

TestFlightApp.com is easy to send. Otherwise use FTP and following the steps mentioned here http://praveenmatanam.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/xcode-4-wireless-iphoneipad-app-distribution-2/